# followable_type 'ApplicationRecord' instead of 'User' in RoR app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, acts-as-follower

in my project I'm using `acts_as_follower` gem, to implement follow/un-follow feature among users

so in my User class, I have

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
   ...
   acts_as_follower
   acts_as_followable
   ...
end
```

but in the db table `Follow`, the `follower_type` is `User` (which is correct) while the `followable_type` is `ApplicationRecord`

I would be very grateful if you could help me understand why, thanks in advance..

some information:

follows_controller.rb:

```
class FollowsController < ApplicationController

def create
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if(current_user!=@user)
        current_user.follow(@user)
        redirect_to users_show_path(:id => @user.id)
        flash[:notice] = "You are now following #{@user.username}."
    end
end

def destroy
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if(current_user.id!=@user.id)
        current_user.stop_following(@user)
        redirect_to users_show_path(:id => @user.id)
        flash[:notice] = "You are no longer following #{@user.username}."
    end
end
end
```

schema.rb:

```
create_table "follows", force: :cascade do |t|
   t.string   "followable_type"
   t.integer  "followable_id",                   null: false
   t.string   "follower_type"
   t.integer  "follower_id",                     null: false
   t.boolean  "blocked",         default: false, null: false
   t.datetime "created_at"
   t.datetime "updated_at"
   t.index ["followable_id", "followable_type"], name: "fk_followables"
   t.index ["follower_id", "follower_type"], name: "fk_follows"
 end
```

follow.rb

```
class Follow < ActiveRecord::Base

  extend ActsAsFollower::FollowerLib
  extend ActsAsFollower::FollowScopes

  # NOTE: Follows belong to the "followable" interface, and also to followers
  belongs_to :followable, :polymorphic => true
  belongs_to :follower,   :polymorphic => true

  def block!
    self.update_attribute(:blocked, true)
  end

end
```

Comment: how do you create the `association`? share code of controller and model `follows_controller.rb`

Comment: @Md.FarhanMemon  I've edited the question, sharing the code, thanks

Comment: ApplicationRecord (as in header) or ActiveRecord (as in description)?

Comment: @MikDiet followable type is ApplicationRecord, sorry for the mistake!

Answer (score 0):

As I see in [gem description](https://github.com/tcocca/acts_as_follower), only master branch supports Rails 5, may be this is a reason.

So you need in your Gemfile, replace

```
gem "acts_as_follower"
```

by

```
gem 'acts_as_follower', github: 'tcocca/acts_as_follower', branch: 'master'
```